# How to trigger independent failure alerts by having common failure handling activity for all the activities in azure data factory pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Example: In my ADF pipeline, i have A,B,C activities running in parallel and activity D which will be called 'on failure' for all the three (A,B,C) activities. currently my D activity is triggering only if all A,B,C fails. But i want the individual triggers for D, based on the failures of A/B/C activities.
Note:I dont want to duplicate the D activity individually.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use 'if condition' activity to achieve what you want.

[image]

Check the status in A B C status, and then design the condition.

Comment: Thanks for your update. But above flow is triggering the if condition only once but I want to trigger the if condition each time when Aor B orC activity fails. My requirement is to trigger mail when one or more A/B/C activities fails and each failure should trigger one mail each.